# Convert environment emulation v.1.9 to v.2

Tags: magento2, environment-emulation

How to rewrite below code to fix version 2.0

```
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

//Dealing with uninitialized translator!
Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend', true);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please create object in your controller for `\Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface` & access it. File path `magento\vendor\magento\framework\TranslateInterface.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
 /* * @var \Magento\Store\Model\App\Emulation $_appEmulation **/

$this->_appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation(
                                    $storeId, 
                                    \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND
                                    );
```

Take a look more detail: **vendor/magento/module-store/Model/App/Emulation.php**